# The correct design for time series experiment

Tags: r, differential-expression, deseq2

I have a treatment and control in two time points like this

```
> design
                                  condition time
    1       CTRL_24_hrs_replicate1   control   24
    2       CTRL_24_hrs_replicate2   control   24
    3       CTRL_24_hrs_replicate3   control   24
    4  treatment_24_hrs_replicate1        t   24
    5  treatment_24_hrs_replicate2        t   24
    6  treatment_24_hrs_replicate3        t   24
    7       CTRL_48_hrs_replicate1   control   48
    8       CTRL_48_hrs_replicate2   control   48
    9       CTRL_48_hrs_replicate3   control   48
    10 treatment_48_hrs_replicate1        t   48
    11 treatment_48_hrs_replicate2        t   48
    12 treatment_48_hrs_replicate3        t   48
    >
```

I want to test between **treatment** and **control** considering time point 24 hours to 48 hours

I have done like this

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=a,colData=design, design=~time + condition + time:condition)

But at this part I get error, although I am trying different things

> ddsTC <- DESeq(dds, test="LRT", reduced = ~ time + time:condition)
estimating size factors
estimating dispersions
gene-wise dispersion estimates
mean-dispersion relationship
final dispersion estimates
fitting model and testing
Error in nbinomLRT(object, full = full, reduced = reduced, quiet = quiet,  : 
  less than one degree of freedom, perhaps full and reduced models are not in the correct order
```

or

```
> ddsTC <- DESeq(dds, test="LRT", reduced = ~time:condition)
estimating size factors
estimating dispersions
gene-wise dispersion estimates
mean-dispersion relationship
final dispersion estimates
fitting model and testing
Error in nbinomLRT(object, full = full, reduced = reduced, quiet = quiet,  : 
  less than one degree of freedom, perhaps full and reduced models are not in the correct order
>
```

I tried these with no error although I am not certain if this makes sense at all while the results of both is the exactly the same

```
> ddsTC <- DESeq(dds, test="LRT", reduced = ~ time + condition)
estimating size factors
estimating dispersions
gene-wise dispersion estimates
mean-dispersion relationship
final dispersion estimates
fitting model and testing
> 

> ddsTC <- DESeq(dds, test="LRT", reduced = ~ time)
estimating size factors
estimating dispersions
gene-wise dispersion estimates
mean-dispersion relationship
final dispersion estimates
fitting model and testing
```

Al I want is getting the difference of treatment versus control but ***considering*** time goes from 24 hours to 48 hours

Thanks for any help